# how to save checkboxes values in node programmatically

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

i want to save checkboxes values in entity reference checkboxes field with node_save
:

```
   $form['wrapperrr']['id_offre'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Liste des Offres'),
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#options' => $optionsoffres,

    );
```

and into the submit button :

```
$node->field_entity_reference['und'][]['value'] =$form_state['values']['wrapperrr']['id_offre'];
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution
:

```
  $aaz= array_filter($form_state['values']['wrapperrr']['id_offre']);
 foreach($aaz as $of)
   {       

  //  $node->title = $form_state['values']['wrapperrr']['id_offre'][0]['value'];     
   $node->field_offre[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['target_id'] = $of;



   }
```